# Ogr2Ogr doesn't work with QGIS 1.8

Tags: qgis, sql-server, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to use `Ogr2Ogr.exe` to import some shapefiles. It came installed with QGIS 1.8. When I try and run it, i get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\bin>ogr2ogr -overwrite -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:serve...<snip> 

ERROR 4: Unable to open EPSG support file gcs.csv. 
Try setting the GDAL_DATA environment variable to point to the 
directory containing EPSG csv files. 
ERROR 6: No translation an empty SRS to PROJ.4 format is known.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\bin>
```

Can anyone help?

It looks like it's an issue with some `PATHS`.

I just opened up a normal command prompt, when to that directory (listed above) and ran the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to set your `GDAL_DATA` environment variable as the error message said. It's at `C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Lisboa\share\gdal` if I'm not mistaken but do check on your machine.

To [manage environment variables](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519/en-us):

> 1. Right-click My Computer, and then click Properties.
> 2. Click the Advanced tab.
> 3. Click Environment variables.
> 4. Click one the following options, for either a user or a system variable:
>
>    - Click New to add a new variable name and value.
>    - Click an existing variable, and then click Edit to change its name or value.
>    - Click an existing variable, and then click Delete to remove

Comment: @RK - is there some documentation which lists what environmental variables I should have set up / check that are set?

Comment: The error message explicitly stated GDAL_DATA. Do start with that. YOu might want to consult this too http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQInstallationAndBuilding#HowtosetGDAL_DATAvariable

Comment: Ta :) that was ze tricksies!